# Installed Drupal 8 in English, added Hebrew, deleted English and now site is malfunctioning

Tags: 8, drush, i18n-l10n

I've deleted the English language from the site (testing purposes - long story) and now when I go to certain pages I get 404 errors (even in the page that will allow me to bring it back - `admin/config/regional/language/add`.

I guess adding & enabling the language with Drush-master could be helpful but I didn't find any such commands at [drushcommands.com](http://drushcommands.com/)

I also tried the following Drupal 7 drush command variations (and others). None worked:

```
drush dl drush_english
drush dl drush_English
drush dl drush_en
```

Maybe there is a manual way to do so which isn't by the UI or Drush?

Ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your permissions? Being UID 1 no longer means full access to everything in D8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is comprised of part1, and part 2:

### Part 1

For some reason, from the moment I deleted the English, each time I went to the pages in the site, including the one I could it bring it back in (`admin/config/regional/language/add`) all of these urls included an "he" (Hebrew) part. For example the add language page was:

```
he/admin/config/regional/language
```

But when I changed the he to en (English) than for some reason I could re-add the English language!

But, even thought it seemed I finished with the problem, another one came in, which I also had to solve:

URL's in the site still redirected with "he" parts even after I deleted the Hebrew language from the language lists, and thus I couldn't even flush all caches from the ui because the URL that instructs cache flushing started with an "he" part.. in the following part 2 I will describe how I solved that:

### Part 2

After I re-added English, and deleted the Hebrew language from the list, I went to the "Detection and selection" tab under "Languaes" at `admin/config/regional/language/detection`, and unchecked there the option **URL:** `Language from the URL (Path prefix or domain), and than I flushed all caches with Drush (the Drupal CLI) and the problem was solved.

I than re-added Hebrew and setted it default language without any problem; Since I changed it's influence on URL's under the "Detection and selection" tab at the Languages page, I didn't have the "he"\"en" parts problem after that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the some problems.

Just don't delete any language.

There is this bag https://www.drupal.org/node/2540876

My sugestion is to save all module and theme, export what you can and instal drupal 8 from begining.

Comment: Oh man, I already installed Drupal 8 three times... It's very annoying to reinstall it each time... Is there a  way I could at least save the taxonomy table and the Content types table with drush (can do manually but with drush it is better); Can you please edit the answer with drush commands for export and import tables? Thanks,

Comment: @benos I am not shure but i didn't see any modules for drupal 8 who do that. In drupal 7 it was this modules https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate or some similer.. Because of that I use manuall backup of database and drupal in cpanel.

Comment: I man, I solved the problem without re-installing, please see my answer above...